# cli : unable to talk to your watchman

Tags: react-native, windows-8.1, watchman

I am new to React Native and I am trying to set up my development environment on Windows 8.1 as described in the official [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

But I have a problem

Steps :

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native start
```

The app doesn't start correctly and I have this error :

```
2020-05-26T18:02:48,578: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on \\.\pipe\watchman-ME! (No such file or directory)

Watchman:  watchman --no-pretty get-sockname returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr= 2020-05-26T18:02:48,578: [cli] unable to talk to your watchman on \\.\pipe\watchman-ME! (No such file or directory)
```

So I figured the problem is with `watchman`

I found the path on this error weird (`\\.\pipe\watchman-ME!`) because when executing `react-native info`, I get the following :

```yaml
System:
    OS: Windows 8.1 6.3.9600
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Memory: 4.36 GB / 7.93 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 13.2.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.19.1 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 6.13.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: 20200424.164118.0 - C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\watchman\watchman.EXE
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.0
      System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.6.0.0 AI-192.7142.36.36.6392135
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_241 - /c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.17 - /c/Python27/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
    react-native: 0.62.2 => 0.62.2
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Is my configuration correct ? Because I read other posts, issues and the best recommendation was to reinstall watchman and reboot. I did it multiple times but no changes. If that matters I downloaded the [latest CI build](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/actions/runs/87211516), extracted it and added it to the path as described in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install/).

But I keep getting the same error, I tried with existing and new projects as well.

**EDIT** :

When I start the app, I said it doesn't start correctly, what happens is that it actually opens a white screen with a green bar saying `Loading from 10.0.2.2:8081 ...`, I read about it ([example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26097)) and I tried every proposed solution, everything seems all right but I keep getting the same error !